# Reactive programming - With default and exception handling

Tags: reactive-programming, spring-webflux, project-reactor, reactor-netty

I am trying to find the best approach for default and error handling with reactive.

This is a working code.

```
public Mono<ServerResponse> retrieveById(ServerRequest request) {
        final String id = request.pathVariable("ID");
        return context.retrieveUser().flatMap(usr -> {
            return repository.findByApptId(Long.parseLong(id), usr.getOrgId()).flatMap(appt -> {
                return ServerResponse.ok().contentType(APPLICATION_JSON).bodyValue(appt);
            });
        });
    }
```

I am trying to add default and error handling.

For default,

```
return context.retrieveUser().flatMap(usr -> {
            return repository.findByApptId(Long.parseLong(apptId), usr.getOrgId()).flatMap(appt -> {
                return ServerResponse.ok().contentType(APPLICATION_JSON).bodyValue(appt);
            }).defaultIfEmpty(ServerResponse.notFound().build());
```

The above default add gives error.

> The method defaultIfEmpty(ServerResponse) in the type
> Mono is not applicable for the arguments
> (Mono)

Same error with onErrorReturn as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Mono#defaultIfEmpty` takes an item `T` and returns a `Mono<T>`. Which means that if you give it a `String` it will return a `Mono<String>`.

You are giving it `ServerResponse.notFound().build()` which returns a `Mono<ServerResponse>` which won’t work since it would give `Mono<Mono<ServerResponse>>`.

What you are looking for is `Mono#switchIfEmpty` which switches producer (Mono) to another producer if the previous one turned out empty.

Comment: Do you recommend any good material for reactive programming?

Comment: The official reactor documentation.